# How to properly release WebGL resources of removed layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I'm working on an application using openlayers 6.7.0 where I dynamically add and remove layers on a map. These layers are WebGL tile layers with GeoTIFF sources. The application features 1..N maps, each map has X layers, and each layer has Y GeoTIFF sources. These layers frequently get removed and replaced by new layers. The maps components rarely get removed or added, but that happens as well.

Despite the complexity, the application and OL are working quite well. However after using the app for a while, my browser starts giving me warnings about too many active WebGL contexts. I've added an example error message with a stack trace at the bottom of this post.

It seems my code or OpenLayers is not removing the WebGL contexts properly and I have not found documentation that explains how removed layers should be cleaned up. The best I have found is `Layer.dispose()` and I've tried to use the following code to remove the removed layers, but this did not resolve the issue:

```js
    const previousLayers = [] as Layer<any>[]
    map.getLayers().forEach((l : Layer<any>) => previousLayers.push(l))
    map.getLayers().clear();
    previousLayers.forEach(l => l.dispose())
```

So my question is: how do I clean up the old layers so that the layers release all underlying resources?

Here is an example error message regarding WebGL contexts. Chrome on Linux, OpenLayers 6.7.0.

```
webgl.js:95 WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost.
getContext @ webgl.js:95
WebGLHelper @ Helper.js:266
WebGLLayerRenderer @ Layer.js:65
WebGLTileLayerRenderer @ TileLayer.js:121
WebGLTileLayer.createRenderer @ WebGLTile.js:303
Layer.getRenderer @ Layer.js:326
Layer.render @ Layer.js:254
CompositeMapRenderer.renderFrame @ Composite.js:122
PluggableMap.renderFrame_ @ PluggableMap.js:1418
(anonymous) @ PluggableMap.js:213
requestAnimationFrame (async)
PluggableMap.render @ PluggableMap.js:1327
Target.dispatchEvent @ Target.js:110
Observable.changed @ Observable.js:72
LayerGroup.handleLayerChange_ @ Group.js:121
Target.dispatchEvent @ Target.js:110
Observable.changed @ Observable.js:72
Layer.handleSourceChange_ @ Layer.js:210
Target.dispatchEvent @ Target.js:110
Observable.changed @ Observable.js:72
Source.setState @ Source.js:178
GeoTIFFSource.configure_ @ GeoTIFF.js:546
(anonymous) @ GeoTIFF.js:348
Promise.then (async)
GeoTIFFSource @ GeoTIFF.js:346
(anonymous) @ OpenLayersMap.tsx:165
(anonymous) @ OpenLayersMap.tsx:136
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
```

Comment: Is it possible to set l to null?

Comment: Cleaning up WebGL contexts requires active work (calls to the WebGL API), setting something to null is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that the `layer.dispose()` method is not calling dispose on the layer renderer.  This is true for all layer types and is something that is addressed in this proposed pull request: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/12798

In addition to connecting the layer's dispose method to the renderer, that pull request also makes the WebGL tile layer renderer do more work in its dispose method.  Most significantly, it now calls `gl.deleteTexture()` with all of the textures in its tile texture cache.

In the WebGL helper, the change above also makes it so we try to use the ["WEBGL_lose_context" extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_lose_context/) if available.  The effect of calling `extension.loseContext()` is perhaps unknowable – it isn't clear to me if this only simulates losing the context if it isn't already lost or if this actually frees up any resources.  See the [WebGL Public mailing list](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/public_webgl/1611/msg00013.php) for more "context" on this mysterious topic.

By my read of the available documentation, the JS garbage collector is supposed to eventually clean up all this stuff.  Assuming your application no longer has any references to the resources, they should be garbage collected.  We also assume that OpenLayers itself is not hanging on to any references unnecessarily.

It may be that we just have to live with the browser's warning that "Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost."  This is actually what we want – for resources associated with unused context's to be cleaned up.  Ideally, our calling the additional `gl.delete*` methods will allow for cleanup before it would have already happened, but I'm uncertain if there is really any kind of "leak" that we can do anything about here.

The [pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/12798) above also marks the `layer.dispose()` method as part of the public API.  Ideally, you shouldn't have to call these dispose methods (if what we believe about the garbage collector is true).  One other place where we expose this method publicly is for the raster source where we need to know when it is safe to call `worker.terminate()` – but that is another subject.